# Send auto post request in react without a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, post

Normally you send a post request via a submit button on a form. However I need to send a post request without a form. In fact, I need to send post request as soon as the user has selected location & status for a patient.

I tried posting `handleAutoObsSubmit()` on `componentDidUpdate()` however this post request is sent every time there is a DOM update i.e. click on other button, I only want it to send once.

Is it even a thing to send post request like this?

```
    handleAutoObsSubmit = () => {

       const postObsUrl = '/observation/record';
        this.state.patientInfo.forEach(patient => {
            if (patient.locationInfo !== '' && patient.status !=='') {
                const data = {
                    room: patient.room,
                    patient: patient.name,
                    location: patient.locationInfo,                  
                    status: patient.status,
                };
                fetch(postObsUrl, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                    .then((res) => {
                        console.log(data);

                        if (!res.ok) {
                            console.log('request failed');
                        } else {
                            console.log('request sent');
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
}
```

```
  patientInfo = [
        { count: 959999,  room: "1", name: 'John Nero', locationInfo: '', status: ''},
        { count: 959999, room: "2", name: 'Shawn Michael', locationInfo: '', status: ''},
        { count: 959999, room: "3", name: 'Gereth Macneil', locationInfo: '', status: ''}
]
```

Comment: You could probably use the change event handlers on your inputs with some validation logic to send the request when the form has been completed.

Comment: you want `componentDidMount`

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thing its not a form or an input i'm working with. These are buttons users click to set `locationInfo` and `status`.

Comment: @Jereme identify upon which particular action that you want fetch request to trigger and call fetch in that handler

Comment: Which part of your component is calling handleAutoObsSubmit?